# How to troubleshoot not automatically receiving Facebook messages/notifications?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I am not getting any messages/notifications (M/N) both on Facebook.com and Messenger.com both in Firefox and Chrome. I need to manually refresh the page to see if there are any new M/N present, which is very annoying.

It is worth noting that everything works fine in the Facebook and Messenger apps on my Android phone.

As I have said, I have tried two different browsers and it behaves the same in each of them. I have tried to check the developer's console for any errors, but I haven't found any. I have also checked the HTTP requests the pages do after loading. There are some happening periodically, however none bring up the new M/N. I have also tried to report the problem using the form on the Messenger.com website, but as expected, I haven't got any response.

Any ideas how to troubleshoot this further?

Comment: It seems to be like issue try with this [facebook notification](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!starred/chrome/BcgSho7VyTY) the same i am facing too.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the native Facebook Android applications use an API endpoint to retrieve messages which could be the reason that you aren't getting similar expectations on desktop.

Things that you can try

- m.facebook.com
- enabling and disabling notifications via desktop and mobile (toggling)
- a third browser
- a test user to see if it's localised to your account (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users)

Listening to Facebook chat traffic is a bit of a hurdle as an end user, the best within the scope of this site is to look up MQTT protocol and move from there.

Other than that nagging facebook.com/help will be the correct way.